# firebase dynamic link generated via API open appstore

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm creating a dynamic link via API.

How can I specify to open the AppStore if the app is not installed?

here the body for my request:

```
{
"dynamicLinkInfo": {
"domainUriPrefix": "https://wi.page.link",
"link": "https://wiapp.com.au/faq?promocode=mypromo_code",
"iosInfo": {
  "iosBundleId": "com.direce.sr",
  "iosFallbackLink":"id1356389392",
  "iosAppStoreId":"id1368389392",
   },
  "socialMetaTagInfo" :{
  "socialImageLink":"https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/doraemon/images/b/b8/Doraemon_2005.PNG/revision/latest?cb=20151207094313&path-prefix=en",
  "socialTitle":"my titu",
  "socialDescription":"descripotio"
  }  

 },
"suffix": {
 "option":"UNGUESSABLE"
},
}
```

this works if I create the dynamic link via firebase console, where I can specify what to do if app not installed

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok!
found the problem, is the

> "iosAppStoreId":"id1368389392"

it is different value if creating from the dashboard or for API,
so the correct one when doing from, API should be without the "id"

> "iosAppStoreId":"1368389392"

Comment: It did not work for me though. Is it mandatory to set iosFallbackLink also to the AppStoreId?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a parameter called `iosInfo`, which has a property called `iosAppStoreId` (the app store id).

Check the documentation page [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener#parameters).

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, but is not working with iosAppStoreId either

Comment: is there a flag to set to open the appstore if app not installed?

Comment: Remove the `iosFallbackLink` property.

Comment: Tried that also

Comment: I'm not sure then, but are you sure that the `iosBundleId` and `iosAppStoreId` match what is on the firebase console? Because it seems that you added two different app id's for `iosFallbackLink` and `iosAppStoreId`.

Comment: hi, yes thanks is just after editing it to avoid using the real ones... but still not working ;[